# Notepad++ export to pdf or image and keep all formatting and colouring?

Tags: notepad++

I have a notepad++ file that is formatted with spacings etc...
as well as a certain background/text colour I want to keep. How do I export that file to either an image or a pdf that will keep the spacings and the background/text colour?

Comment: why not take a screenshot?

Comment: Cause it's too big, I'd have to spent lots of time splicing them all up :(

Comment: fair enough, then the suggestion by @Logman make sense. You can look at CutePDF that will appear as one of your printers after you install it and you'll be able to convert your notepad file to pdf directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use print functionality to do that. To get background color go to  Settings -> Preferences -> Printing and check WYSIWYG. Also you need to have pdf or image printer. Google for one of them for ex. "pdf printer windows 10".

Edit: 
To make whole page color as background first remove text from header and footer in  Settings->Preferences->Printing it will remove header and footer from print. Second use pdf/image printer options to scale and set position for your document. If there is no options for printer (for ex. win 10 pdf printer ) you can reprint pdf again using pdf reader scaling on print setting. But for pdf if you not set page color as background color you will always see a little white borders.

Comment: Nice, seems to work fine. Though it comes up with margins that are white (header/footer), how do I remove those? I tried reducing the font size, but it only goes down to 6.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export it so that you can use it in a Word Document or something, I would suggest to copy-paste it in the Carbon app. https://carbon.now.sh 
You can choose among the theme dropdown to select a background/text colour or you can create your own theme by clicking `+ Create` in the top option.
If you wish to show the line numbers, go to `Settings > Window` and check `line numbers`
You can then choose to export it by clicking the "export" button and click the `PNG` option in the `Export as` section.

Comment: Explain a little bit how it works, for example "you can upload a file and select formatting type" etc.. Don't use best, works great, instead just explain what you can do so one can understand if it interesting to click the link or not.

Comment: @Zoe  I edited my answer, you're welcome for any other feedback

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with the answer above, but found a way to capture the color in Notepad++ (I was using the Compare Plug-in).  I used a program called SnagIt. It's not free, but pretty inexpensive. It is a WIndows capture program that allows a vertical scrolling capture.  You can then save the output as PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a browser. For example, open Chrome browser, then press CTRL key and o key together to navigate and open a file in Chrome. Once the file is opened in chrome, press CTRL and p keys and save as PDF or select another format from the menu which shows other options depending on the programs installed on your PC such as OneNote which will save the file as a sequence of editable images, one image for each page.

Answer (score 1):

### Using the notepad++ program

1. Select the **Plugins** tab
2. Select the third option **NppExport**
3. Within this option select

   - **Export to HTML** and save it in the directory you want and remember to save it in
4. Open your favourite browser and drag the file into the browser.

   - Your browser will open it as an html file

     - **Browser Firefox** allows you to use the **Alt** key to open a list of tools which includes opening files found within your system.
5. Now all you have to do is press **Ctrl + P** or look for the print option that all browsers have
6. You would already have the possibility to print the file created in **Notepad++** in **PDF format** including all the possible page settings that the browser allows

Comment: When you have opened the html file in browser then Firefox has an option to save the whole page as an image. Right-click, Take screenshot, Full page.

Comment: The interesting thing about the "print" option is that it converts the pdf content into text which makes it easier to manipulate with pdf readers and editors such as highlighting or underlining words.

Comment: NppExport is not necessarily the third option (in case you have other Plugins installed, e.g. Compare)